# How to do such a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, repeat

I will ask for help from yours.
Example table:

```
| ID | NAME |POINT|
|  1 | alex | 2 |
|  2 | alex | 2 |
|  3 | jenn | 4 |
|  4 | shama| 3 |
|  5 | jenn | 4 |
|  6 | Mike | 1 |
```

I want to find repetitive name and change name value and sum repetitive value.
Like

```
| ID | NAME     |POINT|
|  1 | alexander| 4   |
|  2 | jennifer | 8   |
```

Is it possible mysql query? 
Thanks.

Comment: `SUM(POINTS) GROUP BY NAME`? but then what is the meaning of ID there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select id,
case when name = 'alex' then replace(NAME,'alex','alexander') 
     when name = 'jenn' then replace(NAME,'jenn','jennifer')
     end  as d,sum(point) 
     from name group by d having d is not null;
```

Comment: Really awesome @denny

Comment: if i want to use replace like string.     select point_id,
case when name like 'Alex%' then replace(NAME,"Ale%","Alexander")
         end  as d,sum(quantity)
     from hb_number where point_id=736 group by d having d is not null;

Comment: Do u mean...case  when name = 'search string' then replace(column name,'search string','replace with it')

Comment: Yes exactly denny

Comment: Yes i am getting  0 or 1

Comment: Now i have no computer... but i will give any solution tomorrow as you want

Comment: i'm waiting Impatiently

Comment: No dude...replace() cant allow any function between it...i work hard but yet donot success..

Comment: Same i will do..dude

Comment: Hi, Denny,your answer work great.  if i want to see all result,your answer in   add shama and mike or another. like the top table how i make?

Comment: Sorry for late replay.You sould be use "else" condition in query

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, name, sum(point) as point
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
group by name
having count(*) >= 2;
```